# Entity Framework select object with grandparent ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

With SQL I would do the following...

```
SELECT G.* FROM GOAL G
INNER JOIN Plan P ON
P.planID = G.planID
INNER JOIN User U ON
U.userID = P.userID
WHERE U.userID = @userID
```

In my Controller (MVC4) `"ActionResult Edit"` Im doing the following, which is two queries, how could I do just one?  The goal is to make sure the user is only able to do the "Edit" action on their own data vs. someone else's goal.

```
var plan = db.Plan.Where(b => b.UserID == CurrentUserID).FirstOrDefault();
Goal goal = db.Goals
            .Where(b => b.PlanID == plan.ID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
return View(goal);
```

Model

```
public class Plan
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
[Table("PlanGoal")]
public class Goal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PlanID { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could join Goals and Plan together instead of adding a property to your `Goal` class:

```
Goal goal = (from g in db.Goals
            from p in db.Plan
            where p.UserID == CurrentUserID
             && g.PlanID == p.ID
            select g).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I would prefer this one but it doesnt work in "from p in Plan"...Plan doesn't resolve "its a type but its used like a variable".

Comment: I think that's because I forgot to include the context (`db.`) in the statement.  I updated my answer for that.

Comment: Of course, not sure why I missed that either.  I gave you the answer since it didn't require me to change the model.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Add a **virtual** `Plan` Property to the `Goal` Class

```
public class Goal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public virtual Plan Plan { set;get;}    
    [Required]
    public int PlanID { get; set; } 
}
```

Now you can query it like this

```
Goal goal = db.Goals
            .Where(b => b.Plan.UserID == CurrentUserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked, I originally had those virtuals but had issues with some extra FK's showing up, adding that virtual and redoing the code first migration didn't put the FK back in, your code worked great!  Thanks!